# How to change text fontsize from onchange()

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the fontsize of a text html element from an onchange().

Here is my code :

```
<input onchange="myf();" type="number" name="font_size_number"    id="mycontroller">

<script>
function myf(){
document.getElementById('mytext').style.fontSize='"'+document.getElementById('mycontroller').value+'px"';
}
</script>

<text id="mytext">tarara</text>
```

Comment: what are you trying to change and when?

Comment: So what the issue are you facing ?

Comment: Please provide more information about the errors, the code, and how you triy to fix it. And for better undertanding, read this [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I just moved some quotes around I think

```
myf = function(){
    document.getElementById('mytext').style.fontSize=document.getElementById('mycontroller').value+"px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/16mgy0xm/9/

```
<script>
  function myf() {
    var size = document.getElementById('mycontroller').value;
    document.getElementById("mytext").style.fontSize = size + "px";
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using inline event handlers (onchange=...) and use standards.  The following works:

```
 <input type="number" name="font_size_number" id="txtNumber">
 <text id="txtOutput">This is the output area.</text>

 <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
         var txtNumber = document.getElementById('txtNumber');
         var txtOutput = document.getElementById('txtOutput');
         txtNumber.addEventListener("change", function(){
              txtOutput.style.fontSize = txtNumber.value + "px";
         });
    );
 </script>
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/sxsbcdy2/